# Recover a disconnected mapped drive

Tags: networking, hard-drive

Is there anyway to recover a mapped drive that was disconnected without knowing the server address or name? I do not want to browse through over 85 server ips to find the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is under Windows and the drive mapping wasn't outright removed from your computer, use `Windows Explorer` to view the `My Computer` pane, then double-click on the network drive. Attempting to use it should cause Windows to attempt to reconnect the drive.

If the mapped drive was removed, you would need to know the address of the computer to re-establish the mapped drive since you are essentially creating it from scratch rather than simply reconnecting it.

Comment: I believe he means it has been fully disconnected, in which case it won't show under My Computer.

Comment: That being the case, you would need to know the address of the computer to re-establish the mapped drive since you are essentially creating it from scratch rather than simply reconnecting it. Edited answer to indicate that as well.